# perserve file permissions when distributing from *nix to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, permissions, acl

I have some files on Linux that I'd like to zip them and distribute to users with Windows. There are specific permissions set on them and I'd like them to have same/similar file permissions when the user extract them on Windows. I did quite some googling and there seems to be no way of doing this since file permissions are OS specific and there is no direct conversion between Unix and Windows.
My question is then: What is the standard approach to this when it comes to cross platform distributions? Am I not supposed to do anything about the file permissions? I would assume that if I have 700 on foo.txt on Linux, I should do something similar so when the Windows user extract the zip, the owner of foo.txt has Full permission and no other permissions should be set on it.

Edit:

Use case: The Windows machine might have many users on it. If I, as user "user1", extracts the files onto some directory to which a certain user group has read/write permission (as far as I know you can define a user group and give that group read/write permission), the files will inherit the permissions from the directory, making it writable by everyone in the user group. Now someone else can come in and mess with my files.
I know that the user can avoid this by changing the permissions after extraction, but I as the distributor would like to help the user as much as possible. In Unix there's no additional work to do since a "700" should ensure that only the owner can do anything to the file.

Comment: That's not helping the user, that's hurting the user.  If I chose to extract the files onto some directory to which a certain user group has read/write permissions, I did so because I *wanted* that user group to have read/write permissions to the extracted files.  If I didn't want those users to have access, I'd have extracted the files somewhere else.  If you force different permissions, I'll have to go back and reset them, which will make me cross.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks. What you said makes sense. So is this the usual mentality for Windows users? From Linux's perspective, I don't care where I put the file as long as I have the permission bits set properly.

Comment: Well, it's not like I've personally consulted every Windows user in the world. :-)  But I think so, yes.  (I suspect the historical difference is because traditionally UNIX homes were at least world-readable by default, so users had to cordon off specific files and folders they didn't want to share; on Windows, home directories are private by default and traditionally if you wanted shared folders you had to set them up explicitly.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows, all of a user's folders are private by default.  In order to share files with other users you must explicitly choose to use one of the standard Public folders, or set up a shared folder of your own.

For this reason, the usual convention is for extracted files to inherit the same permissions as the folder they were extracted into.  If the user has extracted the files into a shared folder, it should be safe to assume that they did so deliberately because they want the files to be shared.